# Ajax Post send empty variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a variable through an ajax post statement as shown below.

```
var variable1 = "";
var variable2 ="tree";
$.ajax
{
    url: webServiceURL + "AddTask",
    type: "POST",
    data: { ID: variable1 , Value: variable2 }
})
```

When this is run for some reason the ajax request is dropping variable1 as if it doesn't exist. I was hoping there would be a way to force the call to send variable1's data as "". I can make changes to the back end and send null instead of "" but would really rather not have to do that as it will make things a bit more messy.

Comment: jQuery sends it, just tested and empty keys are sent as POST data, but the serverside probably ignores it when parsing the values, and there's not much one can do clientside to fix that ?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I will have to look a bit more into the serverside then thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adeneo mentioned it was to do with my backend. I have had to instead send data back as null and then have this changed to an empty string.